# Can't connect to my android's hotspot

Tags: android, hot-spot

I've tried to run Ubuntu from Live CD to check it. 
Ubuntu recognized my android's hotspot (I use android 2.1 with "Wifi Tethering") but wasn't able to connect to it.

It's really a problem for me because I don't have any other internet connection.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

I've understand sometime that ubuntu 12.04 can't connect to any ad-hoc network. Then I upgraded to 12.10 beta and the problem was solved!

Answer (score 1):

I made bad experiences with the built-in tethering-configs as well. But there is an app-solution that works well, the app is free.

[Free wifi tethering app "Open Garden"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=og.android.tether&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9nLmFuZHJvaWQudGV0aGVyIl0.)

Works well for me.

*Note: I am root on my phone, i don't know how well the provided non-root tethering works. Just set up your connection options and try browsing ;]*

Comment: Thanks. I've tried open garden and it didn't work (I have root). I've understand sometime that ubuntu 12.04 can't connect to any ad-hoc network. Then I upgraded to 12.10 beta and the problem was solved!

Answer (score 0):

This may sound stupid but *try to shorten name (SSID) of your WiFi network*.

I shortened the name of my hotspot from `gunithNexus5AP` to `guNexus` and, voilà, it works! I found the solution in [an old post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2136205) which dates back to 2013, which is ironically still valid in version 17.04.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Though in this case my review was probably mistaken: you already included the relevant part in your answer but your phrasing didn't make clear that it was the only necessary step. In the future please 1) make it clear which actions you're *suggesting* to solve the issue described in the question (instead of simply *stating* what you did) and 2) if applicable cite your source(s) in case somebody wants to investigate further. I'll edit your answer to lead by example and illustrate what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same.
Was trying to connect WiFi tethered from my Samsung S10e Android phone to Ubuntu 18.04 desktop.
The Wifi was able to connect only when I disabled the following 2 options in wifi tethering settings.

1. Power Saving mode, this is different from power saving mode of the mobile. The setting is present separately for wifi hotspot.
2. WiFi sharing - this supposedly allows you to share an existing wifi your phone is connected to via the Wifi hotspot you are creating.

I didn't try to isolate, that which of the 2 was the real culprit. 
For me reducing the length of name of my hotspot didn't work, neither did changing my crda region to India (IN) work.